# Как Python понимает в какую функцию в декораторе передавать функцию обернутую ранее декоратором

Tags: python, функции, декоратор

```py
def outer_decorator(arg1, arg2):
    def middle_decorator(func):
        def inner_decorator(*args, **kwargs):
            print(f"Аргументы для внешнего декоратора: {arg1}, {arg2}")
            print("Дополнительные действия перед вызовом функции")
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            print("Дополнительные действия после вызова функции")
            return result
        return inner_decorator
    return middle_decorator

@outer_decorator("значение1", "значение2")
def my_function():
    print("Оригинальная функция")

my_function()
```

Как питон понимает в какую функцию передавать аргумент (в виде функции `my_function`) в функции (декораторе) `outer_decorator`, ведь в сам `outer_decorator` мы передаём лишь два аргумента `arg1, arg2`, и мы не передаём саму функцию: `my_function`? Но так или иначе мы можем получить её(`my_function`) в `middle_decorator`, хоть мы её никак не передаём и по сути не знаем.

В этом всем и заключается вопрос "как?" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавление обычного декоратора эквивалентно такому коду:

```
func = decorator(func)
```

Добавление параметризованного декоратора эквивалентно сначала вызову внешнего декоратора как функции с указанными параметрами, потом вызова его результата с передачей функции как параметра, на вашем примере это будет выглядеть так:

```
my_function = outer_decorator("значение1", "значение2")(my_function)
```

или если расписать в два этапа:

```
decorator = outer_decorator("значение1", "значение2")
my_function = decorator(my_function)
```

То есть, сначала вызывается внешний декоратор, из него возвращается middle_decorator, он тоже вызывается с передачей в него функции, из него возвращается внутренняя функция-обертка (то что у вас называется inner_decorator), и она перезаписывает исходную функцию.

Если добавить больше print-ов, будет видно, что все выполняется именно в таком порядке. Имена немного поменял.

```
def parametrized_decorator(arg1, arg2):
    print(f"Вызов parametrized_decorator c параметрами {arg1}, {arg2}")
    def decorator(func):
        print(f"Вызов decorator с параметром {func}")
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print("Вызов wrapper")
            print(f"Аргументы для внешнего декоратора: {arg1}, {arg2}")
            print("Дополнительные действия перед вызовом функции")
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            print("Дополнительные действия после вызова функции")
            return result
        
        print("Возвращаем wrapper из decorator")
        return wrapper
    
    print("Возвращаем decorator из parametrized_decorator")
    return decorator


@parametrized_decorator("значение1", "значение2")
def my_function():
    print("Оригинальная функция")

my_function()
```

Вывод:

```
Вызов parametrized_decorator c параметрами значение1, значение2
Возвращаем decorator из parametrized_decorator
Вызов decorator с параметром <function my_function at 0x7fab047c7e20>
Возвращаем wrapper из decorator
Вызов wrapper
Аргументы для внешнего декоратора: значение1, значение2
Дополнительные действия перед вызовом функции
Оригинальная функция
Дополнительные действия после вызова функции
```

При этом вложенные функции создаются в момент вызова внешней функции, и имеют доступ к локальным переменным (в том числе и параметрам) внешней функции на момент этого вызова. И самая внутренняя функция будет знать о параметрах внешних функций.